# Are underscores in URL query parameters valid?

Tags: python, http, url

I have noticed that the URI utilities python library produced by rackspace in 2014 has a parse_query_string method that will strip underscores:

```
>>> parse_query_string("_id=foo")
{"id":"foo"}
```

Is this bad behaviour?  Here is the regex they are using:

```
_QS_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(?<![0-9])([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9\-.]*)=([^&]+)')
```

I noticed that removing the first a-zA-Z set makes it work as expected:

```
_QS_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(?<![0-9])([a-zA-Z_0-9\-.]*)=([^&]+)')
```

Any idea why they did that?

Comment: I don't think think this is bad behavior, sometimes the needs might justify them. But in general, avoiding the underscores will help in creating more readable urls.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern does not match _ as is, so you have to redefine it a little to get _

```
(?<![0-9])([_a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z_0-9\-.]*)=([^&]+)
```

Comment: I don't think the `|`-alteration is needed here. `[_a-zA-Z]` should just work fine.